# p:commandButton throws NPE when I add update attribute

Tags: jsf-2

I'm getting a NPE as soon as I as add the update attribute. I just can't figure out what's wrong with this.

the xhtml is below

```
    <p:dataTable id="mpirList" var="mpir"
    value="#{PIAMpir.mpirModel}" style="margin-top:9px"
    paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20">

    <p:column id="mpirValuecolumn" headerText="MPIR"
        style="width:25px;">
        <h:outputText id="mpirValueTxt" value="#{mpir.mpir}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column id="mpirEffectiveRangecolumn" headerText="Effective Range"
        style="width:25px;text-align:center;">
        <h:outputText id="mpirEffRangeTxt" value="#{mpir.effectiveRangeAndYear}" />
    </p:column> 
    <p:column id="mpirActioncolumn" headerText="Action"
        style="width:25px;text-align:center;">
            <p:commandButton id="updateMpirLink" value="Update" actionListener="#{PIAMpir.updateSel}" update="mpirDetailPanel">                                 
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PIAMpir.mpirs}" value="#{PIAMpir.mpirs}" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PIAMpir.selectedMpirId}" value="#{mpir.mpirId}" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PIAMpir.addNew}" value="false" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PIAMpir.showDetails}" value="true" />
            </p:commandButton >
    </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>  
<p:spacer width="5" height="5" />
<h:commandButton id="addNewMpirLink" value="Add New" actionListener="#{PIAMpir.prepForAddNewMpir}" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PIAMpir.addNew}" value="true" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PIAMpir.showDetails}" value="true" />
</h:commandButton>              
<p:spacer width="50" height="50" />
<p:panel id="mpirDetailPanel" autoUpdate="true" >
```

and the error I'm getting is

[4/18/14 6:33:49:639 EST] 00000044 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet ACHAdminMpir in application ACHProviderInterface-ear. Exception created : javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:369)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaborator.java:143)
at.....

Answer (score 0):

you can't upadte the mpirDetailPanel like this, because it's not in the same namingcontainer as the action source. You have the specify the absolute path.
Assuming the script you provided is in a `h:from` you can achieve this with `update=":formId:mpirDetailPanel"`

Comment: Yes it is in a form and I did try that as well. But forgot to mention that the h:commandButton does work well.                              <h:commandButton id="updateMpirLink" value="Update" actionListener="#{PIAMpir.updateSel}" update="mpirDetailPanel">                                 
               ...................
            </h:commandButton >